# Jenkins pass paramater as an env to the shell script for passing sh to kubernetes pod

Tags: shell, jenkins, kubernetes, jenkins-pipeline, sh

We have a dockerized maven project where we deploy it to the kubernetes via Jenkins and Helm.So the thing that I would like to do is, pass below shell script as a command in deployment.yaml like as below to initate selenium tests while pod is creating. But somehow before I deploy the service, I need to update the variables in shell script according to the conditional statements(jenkins parameters) and then pass to update shell script to the kubernetes pod.

So, is there anyway to add if statements and update variables according to the jenkins parameters and pass through to pod with proper values ?

**Shell Script**

```
#!/bin/sh
    
mvn --projects {$projectName} --also-make clean test -Dcucumber.filter.tags="@${servicename} or @${tag}" -Denvironment=test -Ddhc=true -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=/usr/java/openjdk-14/lib/security/cacerts
```

**Deployment.yaml**

---

```
  env:
    {{- range $key, $value := .Values.extraEnv }}
    - name: {{ $key }}
      value: {{ $value | quote }}
    {{- end }}
  command: ["/test-script.sh"]
```

**Jenkinsfile**

---

```
parameters {    
    string(name: 'projectName', defaultValue: "Xx", description: 'Which project do you want to test?')
    string(name: "service_name", defaultValue: 'Yy', description: 'Selenium tag for service name')
    string(name: "tag", defaultValue: 'must')
    //string(name:'branchName', defaultValue: "origin/development", description: 'Environment for selenium tests')}

    stage('Deploy to dev'){
        steps{
            script{
                   sh """ 
                       helm upgrade --install --debugtest-service --values values.${ENV}.yaml --namespace ${namespace} --set image.tag=${env.BUILD_NUMBER} .
                     """
                }
            }
```

EDIT-1

ı just added my question according to the below answer. So after running sed and update the script, how can I add a if statement to check value of service name parameter? Or can I use something like

```
if [ <PROJECTNAME> == "xx]
```

Here is the steps that I would like to do.

```
    projectName=$1
    serviceName=$2
    tag=$3
    
    if [ "$serviceName" == "xx" ]
    then
        echo "Tests are running "..
        mvn --projects <PROJECTNAME> --also-make clean test -Dcucumber.filter.tags=""@<SERVICENAME> or @<TAG>"" 
    else 
    echo 'All test scenarios are running on stage environment'
    mvn --projects <PROJECTNAME> --also-make clean test -Dcucumber.filter.tags="@<SERVICENAME> or @<SERVICENAME>" -
    fi
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can keep placeholders for such values which requires to be updated dynamically at build time.
I'd keep the shell-script as below with placeholders instead of variables:

```sh
#!/bin/sh
mvn --projects <PROJECTNAME> --also-make clean test -Dcucumber.filter.tags="@<SERVICENAME> or @<TAG>" -Denvironment=test -Ddhc=true -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=/usr/java/openjdk-14/lib/security/cacerts
```

And then add a `sed` line within the `sh block` above your `helm upgrade ...` command to replace the placeholders with build time values so that it can passed to the next set of actions.

```
sh """
sed -i \"s/<PROJECTNAME>/${projectName}/g; s/<SERVICENAME>/${service_name}/g; s/<TAG>/${tag}/g\" /path/to/test-script.sh
helm upgrade . . . 
"""
```

EDIT-1:

```
Example: 
if (serviceName == 'xx') {
    env.TAG = serviceName
} 
sh """
.... other actions
"""
```

Comment: thanks for your useful response.. Is it possible to add if statement for placeholder ? How can I add an if condition using placeholders via comparing jenkins parameters values ?

Comment: @semural, it should not be challenging. You can have conditional values within your shell script or even a bit above your `sh` block using basic groovy syntax.

Comment: thanks again ı just wonder whether if I can use if statement for placeholder or not

Comment: I'm sorry. I'm not sure if I understood. Can you explain your scenario better? probably with an example. Please add the scenario as an EDIT-1 with your existing question.

Comment: I don't see a need for servicename as a build parameter in tour EDIT case. However, have a serviceName variable set to all test scenarios by default and have an if condition in groovy syntax checking if service name is this, then also set the tag value same as service name. By this you can have the same script and apply changes based on the groovy conditions.

Comment: I got it.. It also much easy to manage this in jenkins ı guess before running sed. Thanks again

Comment: have added an EDIT-1 from my end for your query. Glad it helps.